# How to disable the copy,past,select,selected all, in safari when I making a Web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am trying to make the web app more native, so I want to disable these functions when tap and hold the web page. Please help me how to do.Thanks.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you want to achieve, what you have tried and what your stumbling blocks were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not portable for all browser (terrible thing!) but you can write this CSS code:

```
*
{
 -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```